# How do i create multiple PDF's from a single XML in Apache FOP

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I'd like to render multiple reports (PDFs) from a single XML file in Apache FOP.
Each Statement node should create separate PDF's.

I have successfully created a single PDF so far. Below is a sample XML format where each Statement node must be mapped to a separate PDF.

```
<Statements>
<Statement>
<SummaryDetails> 
<SummaryDetail>
</SummaryDetail>
</SummaryDetails>
</Statement>
<Statement>
</Statement>
</Statements>
```

XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
            xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" exclude-result-prefixes="fo">

<xsl:template match="Statement">

<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
             xmlns:rx="http://www.renderx.com/XSL/Extensions"
             xmlns:fox="http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/extensions"
             xmlns:afp="http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/extensions/afp">
<fo:layout-master-set>
<fo:simple-page-master master-name="A4" page-height="29.7cm" page-width="21cm" margin- 
top="1.44cm" margin-bottom="1.25cm" margin-right="0.5cm">
<fo:region-body/>
</fo:simple-page-master>
<fo:simple-page-master  master-name="A4-first" page-height="29.7cm" page-width="21cm" 
margin-top="1.25cm" margin-bottom="1.25cm" margin-left="1.5cm" margin-right="0.5cm">
<fo:region-body region-name="body"/>
</fo:simple-page-master >
</fo:layout-master-set>
<fo:page-sequence master-reference="A4" id="first">
<fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
</fo:flow>
</fo:page-sequence>
</fo:root>
</xsl:template>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#element-result-document

Comment: The advice from @siebe-jongebloed to use `xsl:result-document` to generate multiple output files is because FOP will produce only one PDF file from each input document. (There are formatters that can do multi-document output.) Alternatively, you could look at PDF utilities to break up the output document, which might be difficult if statements can have a varying number of pages.

Comment: XProc can also help with that as a XSLT step using XSLT 2 or 3 can pipe its result documents to an xsl-formatter step e.g. https://xmlcalabash.com/docs/reference/p-xsl-formatter.html